# How to change the application language in IOS from within the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I am making application in which user can choose two languages, English or Arabic.

This option is shown in a custom view. But when user chooses Arabic, the app should change to that language.

I know we can use localized strings and by editing device languages. But this is not I want. When the user chooses Arabic within the app the whole app should changed to Arabic.

Please help.

Comment: Yes its possible, but if you're not using the device language you have to build your own localization system and manually map the requested strings to the localized versions for the selected language

Comment: you should use the device settings or search for duplicates of this question

Comment: This not duplicate at all @Wain

Comment: @DaniellaD'Cruz : Welcome to Arabic world.. There are many post or documents over internet...

Comment: how does it not work for you - you need to give specific details